# If $H$ is a normal subgroup of a finite group $G$ and $|H|=p^k$ for some prime $p$. show that $H$ is contained in every sylow $p$ subgroup of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

If $H$ is a normal subgroup of a finite group $G$ and $|H|=p^k$ for some prime $p$. show that $H$ is contained in every sylow $p$ subgroup of $G$

**Attempt:** $|H|=p^k \implies |G|=p^{n_1} q^{n_2} r^{n_3} \cdots~~|~~n_1 \geq k$

Now, $H$ is also a normal sub group of $G$ and we need to show that $H$ is contained in every $p$ sylow subgroup of $G$ which means in all of $H_{p^{n_1}}, H_{q^{n_2}},H_{r^{n_3}},  \cdots $

Unfortunately, I am not able to decide the strategy to move ahead. How do I move forward?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hints:

1. Since $H$ is normal, what do you know about the conjugates of $H$?
2. What do the Sylow theorems tell you about how different Sylow $p$-subgroups are related, for any given prime $p$?

Comment: Since $H$ is normal, any conjugate of $H$ is $H$ itself... For a given prime $p$, the different sylow subgroups are conjugates....

Comment: But $H$ may not be a sylow $p$ group, hence, how can I make use of these hints?

Comment: You know that $H$ has order a power of $p$, so it must be contained in a maximal $p$-subgroup, which is a Sylow $p$-subgroup.

Comment: Yeah .. So, if the maximal $p$ subgroup containing $H$ be $K_1$ such that $|K_1|=p^n$, then $K_1$ is a sylow $p$ subgroup of $G$. Let $K_1$ and $K_2$ denote two sylow $p$ subgroups of $G$.Let $H$ be contained in $K_1$. Then, $K_2$ is a conjugate of $K_1$. However, the conjugate of $H$ is $H$ itself, hence, it is contained in $K_2$ as well. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Good job.

Comment: If H is self-conjugate then why will it be contained in $K_2$?

Answer (score 4):

Another strategy: if $G$ is a finite group and $N \lhd G,$ then whenever $X$ is a subgroup of $G,$ then $XN = NX$ is a subgroup of $G$ of order $\frac{|X||N|}{|X \cap N|}.$ Now consider the case that $H = N$ and $X \in {\rm Syl}_{p}(G).$